# How to display selector in ListView

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to dispaly ListView and at bottom of my List I have to display two buttons (scroll up/down).

Whenever user press on these buttons my list should scroll accordingly.

for this I have used

```
 if(view == scrollupbtn)
    {
        if(listViewPosition >= 1)
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(-- listViewPosition);

    }
    else if(view == scrolldownbtn)
    {
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(++ listViewPosition);

    }
```

This code able to scroll my listview but I am not able to see list item selector when I press my buttons..

I want to display default list item selector when I press my buttons..

Please let me know what to do for this..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display view in the bottom of the list you can use `addFooterView` method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean

Comment: I need to display selector when I am scrolling my list with buttons.

Comment: I suppose that the only way you can have control buttons for your ListView is to have them outside of ListView, in another view